# My swiper with Swiperjs only autoplays after page reload in Nuxt 3 / Vue 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, swiper.js, nuxtjs3

I'm using a Swiperjs Slider in a Nuxt3/Vue3 Component. The data is received via a prop from its parent page.

Everything works well but the slider only autoplays after I reload the page. All the other options of Swiperjs seem to work fine. Any ideas? Maybe I need to load the Swiper earlier somehow?

This is my Swiper Component (I leave out the CSS):

```html
<script>
// Import Swiper Vue.js components
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/vue";

// Import Swiper styles
import "swiper/css";
import "swiper/css/pagination";
import "swiper/css/navigation";
import "swiper/css/autoplay";

// import required modules
import { Navigation, Pagination, Autoplay } from "swiper";

export default {
  props: ["werkBilder"],
  components: {
    Swiper,
    SwiperSlide,
  },
  setup() {
    return {
      modules: [Pagination, Navigation, Autoplay],
    };
  },
};
</script>

<template>
  <swiper
    :autoplay="{
      delay: 5000,
      disableOnInteraction: false,
    }"
    :spaceBetween="30"
    navigation
    :modules="modules"
    class="mySwiper"
    :style="{ position: 'unset' }"
  >
    <swiper-slide v-for="(item, i) in werkBilder" :key="`slice-item-${i}`">
      <prismic-image :field="item.bild" />
    </swiper-slide>
  </swiper>
</template>
```

The parent is a dynamic page and created like this:

```html
<script setup>
const route = useRoute();
const name = route.params.uid;
const { client } = usePrismic();
const { data: werk } = await useAsyncData(name, () =>
  client.getByUID("werk", name)
);
if (!werk.value) {
  throw createError({ statusCode: 404, statusMessage: "Page Not Found" });
}
const page = werk.value.data || false;
const werkBilder = werk.value.data.slices[0].items;
</script>

<template>
  <div class="container outer-werk">
    <div v-if="page" class="container-werk">
      <slider :werkBilder="werkBilder" />
    </div>
    <NavWerk />
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Not a professional but this is maybe coming from the fact that you're using `setup()` for your `modules`? Also, please import all the JS at the top, then the CSS. In your first snippet, you're doing `JS + CSS + JS`.